# Limiting characters inside HTML paragraph

Tags: html, limit, words, paragraph

I want to make it so there's only 350 characters inside the paragraph, regardless of how many characters are put into it, I only want 350 displayed.

How can I do this?
The text is just in a div tag in

text.

Cheers

Comment: Duplicate of the question that you asked two hours ago.

Comment: It's similar, but it's a different thing. That was to do with my ASP control panel, this site is written in XHTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the text into a textbox, style away the fact that it's in a textbox and then limit the length on the textbox using the size attribute.

However, the ideal solution would be to limit it on the server side.

Comment: don't forget to disable the text box so people can't edit the contents!

Answer (score 0):

You can also inspect the contents via the DOM in JavaScript if you feel like a client-side solution.